# Bashscript which returns link from /proc

Tags: bash, proc, readlink

I would need a script, which return me the symbolic link of /proc/$pid/cwd. I wrote some code, but it won't work!

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=26086

readlink /proc/$pid/cwd
```

I also tried:

```
echo $(readlink /proc/$pid/cwd)
```

The first one returns nothing and the second one gives me a blank line. It kind of looks like it can't access /proc but if I do this by hand

```
# readlink /proc/26086/cwd
```

it works and gives me a symbolic link!

Any ideas?

Comment: If your script has DOS line endings, the value of `pid` is actually `26086\r`, which would cause the behavior for are describing. (For that matter, the argument to `readlink` would be `/proc/26806\r/cwd\r`.) Using `$(...)` would be wrong in any case, because you would be attempting to run the resulting path name as a command.

Comment: @chepner I work on gentoo and used as editor emacs so I don't see why there should be DOS line ending, but if there is how can I get rid of that?

Comment: It worked here. Are you sure there was a process with PID 26086 at the time of your tests?

Comment: @damienfrancois yes because I used than echo aswell and by executing it in the bash it worked

Comment: Is it possible that it is a permission problem?